# Is there a better way to open a file while skipping a line?

Tags: haskell

I want to open a file and skip the first line.  This is what I have come up with:

```
h :: IO Handle
h = do h' <- openFile "foo.dat" ReadMode
       _  <- hGetLine h'
       return h'
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know if it's better, but this would be one alternative (assuming you don't need the handle for something else): `tail . lines <$> readFile "foo.dat"`

Comment: That doesn't meet the spec. I don't want to read the entire file here. I want to have a handle that points to the second line. Reading the rest of the file is an entirely different problem.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard well, but in `ReadMode` all you can do, really, is _read the file_, anyway. And often it's actually the best thing to use `readFile` to do just that: read the entire file into a string and be done with the IO. For dealing with plain string data is much nicer than having to worry about side-effects. — Note that this does _not_ require the program to halt there and wait until the whole file contents are processed: it's lazy, i.e. only the lines you actually need are read. Though this can also cause some nasty surprises; reading it all strict is safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function called `hSeek` which may be what you're after.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSeek

Have an experiment with that using GHCi, I'd recommend.